# Rails Assets - 404 with .map extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I am getting the following error for several of my assets in my Rails app.

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/jquery-1.10.2.min.map")
```

Can anyone shed some light on where the ".map" is coming from and why? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's related to the new [source map](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/) support that started shipping in jQuery [1.9RC1](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/01/09/jquery-1-9-rc1-and-migrate-rc1-released/#sourcemaps).

You can either follow the directions from the 1.9RC1 link and add the compressed, uncompressed, and map files to your `vendor/assets` directory or remove the source map line from the uncompressed file (it looks like `//@ sourceMappingURL=jquery-1.10.2.min.map`).

Hope that helps.

Comment: still, how one would shut down those urls with some catch-all rails route ?