# non existing file in log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When i look at my logfile i see this:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/jquery.cycle2.js.map"):
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/underscore-min.map"):
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/bootstrap.css.map"):
```

I have the files jquery.cycle2.js, underscore-min and bootstrap.css and i have added them with the stylesheet_link_tag nad the javascript_include_tag

But it seems like that .map is added but there are no files with the .map.

please any help...thanks...remco

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393052/rails-assets-404-with-map-extension